# How to center the pictures to the same baseline on beamer titlepage?

Tags: baseline

[image: The left picture is a bit lower than the right]

Here is part of the code i used,

```
\titlegraphic{
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{NCSE} 
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{KENT-Blue}
}
```

I dont know the exact name on how to refer to this problem. But if you look at the picture, the NCSE logo is a bit lower than the Kent logo.

Is that possible to adjust it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\raisebox` to adjust the height. It's a trial and error process, but it works fine.

```
\titlegraphic{
    \raisebox{10pt}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{NCSE}}
    \hfill%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{KENT-Blue}
}
```

Or, you could use `\raisebox` for the second picture, and put in a negative value for the first argument.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `adjustbox` package with `export` option so that you can use `valign=b` in the options of `\includegraphics` command itself.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\title{Title}
\author{A.~Author}
\institute{MWE}
\titlegraphic{
    \includegraphics[valign=b,height=1.5cm,width=2cm]{example-image-A}
    \hfil%
    \includegraphics[valign=b,height=2cm,width=2cm]{example-image-B}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is another attempt. `minipage` is used with [b] alignment

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\title{Title}
\author{A.~Author}
\institute{MWE}
\titlegraphic{
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=2cm]{example-image-A}
\end{minipage}
    \hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[height=2cm,width=2cm]{example-image-B}
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```